# NSManagedObject become nil in cellForItemAt indexPath

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am using collectionView with Horizontal scrolling.At viewdidload I am fetching coredata objects.

```
var listOfArticles  = [Article]()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
     listOfArticles =   CoreDataManager().fetchArticleWithCategory(category: "Entertainment", limit: 10)!
}
```

When i used to print listOfArticles in viewdidload.

```
for newData in listOfArticles {
            print(newData.article_id)
        }
```

> output :-

```
1599845
1599844
1599841
1599838
1599836
1599827
1599823
1599820
1599813
1599811
1599806
```

At indexPath.item == 0 I am able to fetch `Article` objet But indexPath.item == 1 `Article` objet become null.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell :NewsCollectionViewCell  = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! NewsCollectionViewCell
        var articles = listOfArticles[indexPath.item]
        cell.currentArticleToShow = articles
        if let newVar = articles.articleToSectionRel?.allObjects {
            cell.currentSections = newVar as! [Section]
        }
    }
```

When i am try to print **po articles** at indexPath.item == 0

> Output:

```
 <Article: 0x60800009f2c0> (entity: Article; id: 0xd000000000100024 <x-coredata://BA36E40C-6783-4CBF-8C2F-F596ABF1CD56/Article/p4> ; data: {
    articleToSectionRel = "<relationship fault: 0x600000426a00 'articleToSectionRel'>";
    "article_id" = 1599845;
    "book_mark" = 0;
    category = Entertainment;
    "image_url" = "http://images.newindianexpress.com/uploads/user/imagelibrary/2017/4/20/original/KatyPerry-AP1.png";
    "modiffied_date" = "2017-05-01 16:52:00";
    "sub_category" = English;
    summary = "http://images.newindianexpress.com/uploads/user/imagelibrary/2017/4/20/original/KatyPerry-AP1.png";
    title = "Katy Perry courts controversy\U00a0comparing her black hair to Barack Obama";
    topStorie = 0;
})
```

When i am try to print **po articles** at indexPath.item == 1

> Output:

```
<Article: 0x608000280370> (entity: <null>; id: 0xd000000000180024 <x-coredata://BA36E40C-6783-4CBF-8C2F-F596ABF1CD56/Article/p6> ; data: <fault>)
```

When i used  `listOfArticles` inside the `cellForItemAt`.I am getting Article objet at indexPath.item == 1.

```
  listOfArticles =   CoreDataManager().fetchArticleWithCategory(category: "Entertainment", limit: 10)!
```

Why Articles object become null at object indexPath.item == 1 When i fetch data into viewdidload ?. thanks in advance.

Comment: That looks correct.  Your article at index 1 is a fault; it hasn't been fetched yet. Core Data will convert the fetch into an actual object once a property is accessed.  Try `po articles["article_id"]`

Comment: Update the question..

Comment: I don't see a null object

Comment: entity: <null> in nsmangedobject in cellForItemAt indexPath at indexpath.item = 1.

Comment: As I said, that is a fault.  Core Data will resolve the fault when required.

Comment: You are creating new object `CoreDataManager()`   hope your context is shared or global other wise you get nil check my question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37006564/core-data-fault-after-use-one-time

Comment: The easiest way to debug is to create a didSet{} function for listOfArticles, and see who changes this after it's fully fetched in viewDidLoad()

Comment: @MikeAlter thanks for reply, exactly same problem.